# PLSQL - How to subtract time (hh:mi) on timestamp type

Tags: plsql, timestamp, subtraction

I have two fields with timestamps type, time_in and time_out.
For example:
 
`time_out = 02-MAY-11 07.30.00.000000 PM` and 
 `time_in = 02-MAY-11 07.57.00.000000 AM`
I want to get the different HOURS from that timestamps field.
How to do that,.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Extract also works on intervals (which is what a direct subtraction between two timestamps gives you).

```
create table times (time_in timestamp, time_out timestamp);
insert into times values(to_timestamp('02-MAY-11 07.57.00.000000 AM'), to_timestamp('02-MAY-11 07.30.00.000000 PM'));
select extract(hour from(time_out-time_in))||':'||extract(minute from(time_out-time_in)) from times;

EXTRACT(HOURFROM(TIME_OUT-TIME_IN))||':'||EXTRACT(MINUTEFROM(TIME_OUT-TIME_IN))   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
11:33
```

Comment: Many thanks Wes, another one, how to compare the result with another time, for example `if [extract result] > [eight hours] then ....`

Answer (score 0):

See the [Extract](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Date-Timezone/EXTRACTgetthehourminuteandsecondfromaTIMESTAMPreturnedbyTOTIMESTAMP.htm) function

From the above:

```
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> --EXTRACT(): get the hour, minute, and second from a TIMESTAMP returned by TO_TIMESTAMP():
SQL>
SQL> SELECT
  2    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JAN-2005 19:15:26',
  3      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS HOUR,
  4    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JAN-2005 19:15:26',
  5      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS MINUTE,
  6    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JAN-2005 19:15:26',
  7      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS SECOND
  8  FROM dual;

      HOUR     MINUTE     SECOND
---------- ---------- ----------
        19         15         26

SQL>
```

Comment: So, do you mean I've to subtract it manually by getting each hour and minutes from those fields,.?